# UICalendarView Overflowing

Tags: swiftui

Kia ora koutou,

I'm writing my first SwiftUI app - a pretty simple affair. Currently, I'm trying to show my data on a UICalendarView so that the user can see which dates do not have any data entered. The challenge I am running into is putting a UICalendarView on the same screen as a form.

#### Attempt 1: UICalendarView inside Form

This results in the UICalendarView overflowing the form and becoming clipped.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Form {
                // Form Here
                Section {
                    CalendarView(
                        interval: DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: Date())
                    ).frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Attempt 2: UICalendarView outside Form

This results in the UICalendarView being the full width of the screen, but it does fit. The downside is that it becomes fixed to the bottom of the view and the form becomes squished at the top and scrolls independently. This is not desirable, either.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Form {
                // Form Here
            }
            CalendarView(
                interval: DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: Date())
            ).frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Screenshots

Here are screenshots from the simulator of what it looks like.
[image]

#### The Goal

To have my form and UICalendarView nicely stacked on top of each other within the same scrolling section.

I figure I must be missing some fundamental piece of knowledge about how views are composed, but at the moment I don't know enough to know what I don't know!

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you: `UICalendarView` when wrapped in a `UIViewRepresentable` for use in SwiftUI is not resizing itself as expected.

I found the following solution: In `func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView` make sure you add the following lines:

```swift
// Make sure our calendar view adapts nicely to size constraints.
calendarView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
calendarView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

By doing this, the underlying `UICalendarView` is not using the whole width of the iPhone. The minimum width and height in iOS 16 seems to be 220 x 210 points for a `UICalendarView` without date decorations.

Comment: You're an absolute saviour – thank you so much! This was exactly it. I'd never have found this because I was too stuck looking at the UICalendarView docs, not the UIView docs. Here's the documentation link for anyone else: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622526-setcontentcompressionresistancep/.

Comment: This causes clipping for me in the vertical axis of the `UICalendarView`

Comment: @VoodooBoot : It's possible that the `UICalendarView` has not enough space in your layout... Without code and screenshot of the problem, it is difficult to help, but perhaps you want to play with `.fixedSize(horizontal: ..., vertical: ...)`.

Comment: @VoodooBoot I'm having the same issue with the clipping of the calendar view. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MrBr without code, it's difficult to help. Perhaps the problem is related to how the calendar is embedded?
If you like, you can checkout my example project [SwiftUI-CalendarView](https://github.com/pd95/SwiftUI-CalendarView) and my `CalendarView` implementation.

Comment: @pd95 I gave up on `UICalendarView` and am using [JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar).

Comment: @pd95 Your example was actually helpful. I can change the size the size of the calendar by using `maxWidth`/`maxHeight` on the frame modifier. Thank you!